# Add same day in a year month column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to add the day 15 in each of the `year_month` column record.

Here an example of what I want to achieve. This applies to all the year_month record. Basically all the year_month records should contain a 15 after the month

From

```
year    month   year_month
-----------------------------
2019    4       2019-04 
2019    6       2019-06
```

To

```
year    month   year_month
-----------------------------
2019    4       2019-04-15
2019    6       2019-06-15
```

Didn't try any code yet as honestly I don't know how to start.

Comment: What is the type of `year-month`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `datefromparts()` function. It takes year, month and day as arguments and produces a date from it. You can hardcoded day 15.

```
select datefromparts(year, month, 15)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful and got exactly what I needed! Didn't know about datefromparts

Answer (score 1):

One more way to do using `CAST()` and `CONCAT()`

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT([year], '-', [month], '-15') AS DATE)
```

Example: `SELECT CAST(CONCAT(2019, '-', 4, '-15') AS DATE)` will result as `2019-04-15`

Comment: @driveg81 You're Welcome. You can upvote the answer if it is helpful. Also you can [accept any one of the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/312043), which is satisfy more with your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If `year_month` is a string, then:

```
update t
     set year_month = year_month + '-15';
```

Once you do this, I would suggest changing the type to a `date`:

```
alter table t alter year_month date;
```

Or, if you just want a date in the table when you select it:

```
alter table t add year_month_date as (convert(date, year_month + '-15'));
```

This adds a computed column which is a date to the table.  You can then select it and use it in queries as you would any other column.